# set id(primary key) as session instead of Password in mvc 4 razor

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I like to set `id`(primary key) as session instead of `password` in mvc 4 razor sql. Thanks everybody!

**My Model**

```
public bool check(string Pass)
{
    bool convert = false;
    string configuration = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(configuration))
    {

        con.Open();
        var sql1 = "select ID(Primary key) from employees where Pass = '" + Pass + "' ";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql1, con);
        convert = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
        con.Close();
        return convert;


    }
}
```

> And this is my controller

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (person.check(person.Pass))
    {
        Session["Pass"] = person.Pass;
        Session.Timeout = 100000;
        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Welcome User'); window.location.href='Home/Mainmenu';</script>");
    }
    else
    {

        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid UserID'); window.location.href='Home/Login';</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Session["Pass"] = person.Pass;
```

changed it into

```
 Session["Pass"] = person.yourPKeyID;
```